# Putting elements on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I put the following elements on the same line? I know it has to do with the display property, but that's the one that always stumps me and can never seem to get to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4137/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="small-video-section">
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
      <img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/yKWoPlL2B8I/mqdefault.jpg" width="220" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
      <img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/yKWoPlL2B8I/mqdefault.jpg" width="220" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
      <img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/yKWoPlL2B8I/mqdefault.jpg" width="220" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-last">
      <img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/yKWoPlL2B8I/mqdefault.jpg" width="220" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.small-video-section {
  height: 134px;
}

.thumbnail-container {
  width: 220px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.thumbnail-last {
  width: 220px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: Try this code posted below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You could use `float: left` or `float: right`](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4139/)

```
img {float: left;}
```

Note, you'll have to use [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) which Mr Gallagher explains nicely or follow with any element that has `clear: both;` on it to get the results you expect.

You can position them absolutely

```
img {position: absolute;}
```

and then position one by one using `left` and `right` or margins

```
img.image-one {left: 0: top: 0;}
img.image-one {right: 300px; top: 0;}
img.image-three {margin-left: 100px;}
/*etc etc...*/
```

EDIT: didn't notice the divs, you should put float left on those as someone else mentioned, however both options technically work in your case. Theres probably a dozen more ways to do this...

Answer (score 3):

Changing `display:block` to `display:inline-block` in your `.thumbnail-last` rule will do it.

Answer (score 0):

try `float: left` on the divs. That will get everyone to show up in line. other wise block elements introduce a break

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :- Use only `float:left`

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="small-video-section">
        <div class="thumbnail-container"  style="float:left;height:134px;width:150px">
          <img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/yKWoPlL2B8I/mqdefault.jpg" width="150" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail-container" style="float:left;height:134px;width:150px">
          <img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/yKWoPlL2B8I/mqdefault.jpg" width="150" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail-container" style="float:left;height:134px;width:150px">
          <img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/yKWoPlL2B8I/mqdefault.jpg" width="150" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail-last" style="float:left;height:134px;width:150px">
          <img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/yKWoPlL2B8I/mqdefault.jpg" width="150" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

All  your code are ok. But , I have only added `style` in HTML part.

Update link :-

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4148/

Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but it cames when searching for place elements on the same line with bootstrap so I will help others.

Boostrap has the Inline form class to place some elements on the same line (it's left aligned). 
[Bootstrap CSS inline form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)

Comment: It's not a form he is making, so [Bootstrap's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) would be a better solution.

Comment: With the grid system it's hard to force elements to be on the same line without using display property